# Different java versions on mac machine?

Tags: java, macos, path

There is something going wrong with my java configuration and it is really bugging me. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and after downloading and installing java 8 I tried to configure my project to use that SDK but I could only locate version 1.6 under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. I am new to OS X and I am really confused with the paths.
Looking on my Java control panel I can see I got installed Java 8 but after running `java -version` on the terminal I get `1.6.0_65`.
And the `which java` gives back `/usr/bin/java`.
Please help I am completely lost

Comment: i think you have to change the version in settings | java compiler

Comment: I think you need to reinstall the java8 SDK and from the intellij IDEA, when you create a java project, we need to select the java sdk path from the IDEA interface.

Comment: Yep, I tried that but I cannot locate the path. As when I run 'which java' in cmd I get the path for the wrong version

Comment: The problem is that the 1.8 JDK is not even under the JavaVirtualMachines dir...

Comment: http://andrew-jones.com/blog/managing-multiple-versions-of-java-on-os-x/

Comment: I wanna do that manually. There is certainly a way!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with several Java versions installed side-by-side ...

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk1.7.0_25.jdk jdk1.7.0_72.jdk jdk1.8.0_05.jdk jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
```

User can edit  `~/.profile` to point explicitly at one

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And here is result ...

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: the problem is that I dont have any other JDK under that path apart from 1.6. Trying to remove and reinstall and see if it makes any difference now

Answer (score 0):

Well something was wrong with the installation. I completely removed the other versions (not 1.6) and reinstalled 1.8 using the default path (as there is no option to change it during installation. Now IntelliJ can see JDK 1.8
Thanks for the help anyway